# Scrollbar appearing inside my website

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my website.
http://flightsdubai.org/America/Dubai-to-America.php5

There is a mystical scrollbar that appears inside my content window.

http://flightsdubai.org/Asia/Dubai-to-Asia.php5 is based on the same template, yet there is no mysterious scrollbar there.

Has anyone had this problem before?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `overflow-x:hidden` from the `mainContent` and then change `display:block` into `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 0):

just remove the `overflow-x: hidden;` and give the `overflow: hidden;` to your this class `.maincontent`

i hope this will work........

**UPDATED CSS**

```
.mainContent {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```